# How to parametrized docker registery in a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile and would like to parameterize the docker registry so I can pass different values at runtime

```
FROM $REGISTERY/xyz/image_name:tag

ENV....
```

How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use global args, You should pass some default value to make it work.

```
ARG REGISTERY=default.registry.com
FROM $REGISTERY/xyz/image_name:tag
```

So if you want to override during the time just pass

```
docker build --build-arg REGISTERY="myregistry.com" -t testimage .
```